# I want to add two tables in my database, how do I do it?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am a beginner and I did this but I do not know how to add another table
How do I do it? I want to add Admin table in my ussd database.

Here is my code.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ussd.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "offre_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "CODE";
    public static final String COL_3 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "USSD";
    public static final String COL_5 = "SMS";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CODE INTEGER,NAME TEXT,USSD TEXT,SMS TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String code, String name, String ussd, String sms){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,code);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,ussd);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,sms);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a tadabase?

Comment: SQLite.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just handle the creation of all your tables in the `onCreate` method, and the corresponding update or drop and recreation in the `onUpgrade`.

Remember to uninstall and reinstall your app to make the test, or to increase the database version (the "1" in the `DatabaseHelper` constructor). Otherwise, your pre-existing database will not be updated with the new tables, because the system checks if it is updated looking at the version number, not at the structure.

You should also use the constants you defined in the creation statement, I see that you have them repeated. So:

```
db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CODE INTEGER,NAME TEXT,USSD TEXT,SMS TEXT)");
```

becomes:

```
db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_2 + " INTEGER, " + COL_3 + " TEXT, " + COL_4 + " TEXT, " + COL_5 + " TEXT)");
```

Comment: Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add another table by including it inside `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CODE INTEGER,NAME TEXT,USSD TEXT,SMS TEXT)");
    db.execSQL(//SQL to create second table//);
}
```

Comment: I added db.execSQL (// SQL to create second table //);
But the table does not create.

Comment: You need to replace //comment part with actual SQL statement.

Comment: db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME1 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT ,NUMERO INTEGER)");                      like this?

Comment: What is the error? You need to declare your second table name as a String and assign to TABLE_NAME.

Comment: public static final String TABLE_NAME = "offre_table";  public static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "admin_table";    like this?

Comment: `public static final String TABLE_NAME = "offer_table"; public static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "admin_table; db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CODE INTEGER,NAME TEXT,USSD TEXT,SMS TEXT)");db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME1 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT ,NUMERO INTEGER)");`